# Delete data using SQL Partitioning

Tags: sql, sql-server, partitioning

I want to create a table implementing partition function such that if the number of records becomes 5+1 then the first recor gets deleted For example if the records are 1,2,3,4,5 and we insert 6th record then 1st record gets deleted and remaining records are 2,3,4,5,6

Comment: There is not a simple solution to that problem in sql server. You may be better of implementing that functionality in the business/dal layer of your application.

Answer (score 0):

After your `Insert` you could add something like:

```
delete from mytable
where RecordID <= select(MAX(RecordID)-5 from mytable);
```

So that everything before the 5 most recent rows are deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a trigger after insert to delete the surplus rows. Try this example:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
SET NOCOUNT ON;

create table t (id int identity(1,1), val char(1))
go

create trigger limit_t on t for insert as
  begin
  if (select count(*) from t) > 5
  delete from t where id <= (select max(id)-5 from t);
  end
go

-- insert five rows
insert t (val) values ('a'),('b'),('c'),('d'),('e')
-- insert a sixth and seventh row
insert t (val) values ('f'),('g')
-- retrieve content after last insert
select * from t
-- the table now holds values [c,d,e,f,g]

ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
```

Comment: thank you jpw and LugNutz but i want to achieve it through partitioning.